# Story Identification: Were-animals/shifters lead by human alpha/leader?

Tags: story-identification, werewolf

I'm looking for the title of a book-series - I'm pretty sure it was a trilogy when I ran into it, but books may have been added.  It's possible I may mix in details from other books/series I've read, but most should be correct.

I think the main-character is a teenage girl/young woman.  She becomes the leader/alpha of a pack of were-animals/shifters, even though she herself is not (a were).  She herself has grown up inside a pack of were-animals/shifters - unsure if she's adopted or if all weres in the pack had be "infected" in some way.  I think there were also humans in the pack she grew up in.  I think they're werewolves.

I think the pack she leads is a pack of teenagers, outcasts and others who didn't fit-in with the main pride.  She has been trained to fight, and must face a challenger - I think an ex-boyfriend, brother or someone she rescued.  The fight - as all fights for leaderships - is done in human form.

I think someone is left unconscious or dead on her doorstep.  She plans to become a were, but has to delay it.  I think it's her father (the alpha of the main-pack?) or her boyfriend that was supposed to turn her.

I'm pretty sure this exists as audio-books too.

Does this sounds familiar to anybody?  Does anybody remember the author, the series and the title of the first book?

Comment: This sounds interesting. Do you have any more details such as: When did you read it? What did the cover look like?

Answer (score 6):

I think the Series you are looking for is:

[Women of the Underworld](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_of_the_Otherworld) by [Kelly Armstrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelley_Armstrong)

and your description of the Novel description matches the first book in the series:

Bitten

Link: [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?33238)
Link: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitten_%28novel%29)

The other Novels in the Series are:

[Stolen(2003)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolen_%28Armstrong_novel%29)

[Dime Store Magic (2004)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dime_Store_Magic_%28novel%29)

[Industrial Magic (2004)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industrial_Magic_%28novel%29)

[Haunted (2005)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haunted_%28Armstrong_novel%29)

[Broken (2006)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_%28Armstrong_novel%29)

[No Humans Involved (2007)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Humans_Involved_%28Armstrong_novel%29)

[Personal Demon (2008)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Demon_%28Armstrong_novel%29)

[Living with the Dead (2008)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Living_with_the_Dead_%28Armstrong_novel%29)

[Frostbitten (2009)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1016994)

[Waking the Witch (2010)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waking_the_Witch_%28Armstrong_novel%29)

Spellbound (2011)

Thirteen (2012)

Answer (score 2):

[Raised by wolves](http://www.goodreads.com/series/40852-raised-by-wolves) by Jennifer Lynn Barnes? Its a trilogy.

> Adopted by the Alpha of a werewolf pack after a rogue wolf brutally
>   killed her parents right before her eyes, fifteen-year-old Bryn knows
>   only pack life, and the rigid social hierarchy that controls it.  That
>   doesn't mean that she's averse to breaking a rule or two.
>
> But when her curiosity gets the better of her and she discovers Chase,
>   a new teen locked in a cage in her guardian's basement, and witnesses
>   him turn into a wolf before her eyes, the horrific memories of her
>   parents' murders return. Bryn becomes obsessed with getting her
>   questions answered, and Chase is the only one who can provide the
>   information she needs.

Comment: Can maybe add some info and explain why you think this is the story?