# Shifter book series with the alpha's daughter as the main character through out the series

Tags: story-identification

Want to go back and finish a romance/suspense series I started a couple years ago and can't remember author, character names or anything extremely helpful except for the story.

The series is about the alpha's daughter who is being trained as a protector of the pack, and eventually has to take over as alpha down the line. Her boyfriend is training her in the first book and ends up being hated by her uncle who tries to get the council to vote to have her exiled from all packs. A war starts between her dad and uncle and she has to get grizzly shifters and makes a deal with dangerous bird shifters to try and win the main battle.

On the romance end she can't commit to her boyfriend and they're off and on a lot through the series and he ends up being exiled for part of it. She cheats on him when her brother is murdered with her brother's best friend who is in love with her.

I know not a whole lot to go off of but anyone think it sounds familiar?

Comment: I think you are talking about Women of the underworld series by Kelly Armstrong.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40247/story-identification-were-animals-shifters-lead-by-human-alpha-leader/40324#40324

Comment: Relevant meta discussion re: [closing story id questions as dupes](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2952/5184)

Comment: "shifter book"? "alpha daughter"? I don't think these terms are commonplace enough to give your question sufficient context... Though on the other hand, anyone who could answer it would probably understand your terms. I just hoped there would be more details about the *settings* your story takes place in.

Comment: On a side note, don;t go searching for "shifter grizzly" unless you're interested in getting a lot of... er... interesting fiction out there where the gay community term of "bear" gets taken more literally.

Answer (score 2):

The series you're after is literally a series called *[Shifters](https://www.goodreads.com/series/43384-shifters)* by Rachel Vincent. The first book in the series is called *[Stray](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/793399.Stray)*.

> There are only eight breeding female werecats left...
>
> And I'm one of them.
>
> I look like an all-American grad student. But I am a werecat, a shape-shifter, and I live in two worlds.
>
> Despite reservations from my family and my Pride, I escaped the pressure to continue my species and carved out a normal life for myself. Until the night a Stray attacked.

The [synopsis](https://web.archive.org/web/20141016163111/http://rachelvincent.com/prey.html) of Book 4, *Prey*, basically sums up the plot you describe.

> SOMETIMES PLAYING CAT AND MOUSE IS NO GAME...
>
> Play? Right. My Pride is under fire from all sides, my father's authority is in question, and my lover is in exile. Which means I haven't laid eyes on Marc's gorgeous face in months. And with a new mother and an I-know-everything teenager under my protection, I don't exactly have time to fantasize about ever seeing him again.
>
> Then our long-awaited reunion is ruined by a vicious ambush by strays. Now our group is under attack, Marc is missing, and I will need every bit of skill and smarts to keep my family from being torn apart. Forever.

[image: Summary from website]

Comment: Book 4's synopsis basically sums up the OP.  http://rachelvincent.com/prey.html

Comment: for further clarification I have read the series up to book five, I can't recall why I stopped but it was back a few years. After reading the question it was fairly clear to me with the details provided that this was what he was after. Otherwise, there is another book out there that is eerily exact in details.

Comment: I'm rambling now, but I'd also like to add an aside regarding the Women of the Underworld Series, while the basics of that book "sort of" match the OP. The last paragraph does not fit with the Kelley Armstrong series. Nor does the Familial conflift (If I remember correctly).

Answer (score 1):

I think @Madeyedexter's comment hits the nail on the head. This sounds like the Women of the Otherworld series, later retitled to Otherworld by Kelley Armstrong.

The series starts with [Bitten](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11918.Bitten). Elena Michaels is the partner of the Alpha's adopted son rather than the Alpha's daughter, but that's primarily because werewolves do not have daughters. The only way to get a female werewolf is for a woman to survive a werewolf bite. This is rare, and Elena is the only female werewolf in the world.

> Elena Michaels is the world’s only female werewolf. And she’s tired of it. Tired of a life spent hiding and protecting, a life where her most important job is hunting down rogue werewolves. Tired of a world that not only accepts the worst in her–her temper, her violence–but requires it. Worst of all, she realizes she’s growing content with that life, with being that person.
>
> So she left the Pack and returned to Toronto where she’s trying to live as a human. When the Pack leader calls asking for her help fighting a sudden uprising, she only agrees because she owes him. Once this is over, she’ll be squared with the Pack and free to live life as a human. Which is what she wants. Really.

The on again off again relationship is mostly in the backstory. And it's off at the point where Bitten starts. As can be seen in the blurb above. The relationship becomes pretty much on, with mild drama, following the events of the first book. The uncle/brother's friend relationships don't match though.

Elena is being groomed for Pack leadership by the current alpha Jeremy, although it takes nearly 10 books to actually come to something.

There aren't any bird shifters in the series, but [Frostbitten](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4107256-frostbitten), book 10, includes an race of potentially Neanderthal, wolf/bear shifters. The whole thing isn't really very clear, but they're big and more bear-like than wolf-like without being a full animal change like the werewolves are.